# SQL: How to Return string B with n repeated variables for each char in a string A where variable is the position of the char in the string

Tags: sql, string

**How to Return *string B* with n repeated variables for each char in a *string A* where variable is the position of the char in the string**

***For Example***:

- If my string A is"**SQL**"
- The answer I need is "**S1Q2L3**" as ***String B***
- If my string A is"String"
- Then the answer I need is "**S1t2r3i4n5g6**" as ***String B***

So the that the variable changes for each repetition

I needed this for a calculation in Sql.

> Thanks in Advance

Comment: You can try this is in your code than in sql

Comment: "I needed this for a calculation in Sql." - it sounds like there's some *problem* which you've decided on a *solution* where part one is what you're asking about here and part two is this other calculation. I can't help but wonder whether we'd do better if you told us what the overall problem is, because I can't think of many situations where (part of) the right solution to the problem is what you're asking about here.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Comment: its MSSQL..................

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this..

```
DECLARE  @STR VARCHAR(10)='HELLO',
         @Index int=1,
         @TotalLength int,
         @NewStr varchar(20)='';

SET @TotalLength = LEN(@STR);

WHILE (@Index < @TotalLength+1)
BEGIN
    SET @NewStr= @NewStr + (SUBSTRING(@STR,@Index,1)+ CAST(@Index as varchar(2)));
    SET @Index=@Index+1;
END

SELECT @NewStr;
```

Answer (score 1):

For Oracle (as DMBS unspecified):

```
SELECT
LISTAGG(to_char(strings),'') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY rowno) FROM
(
SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR(regexp_replace('STRINGABCXYZ', '(.)', '\1,' ), '[^,]+', 1, lvl) 
    || row_number() OVER (ORDER BY NULL) as strings
,row_number() OVER (ORDER BY NULL) AS rowno    
FROM DUAL, 
(SELECT LEVEL lvl
,regexp_replace('STRINGABCXYZ', '(.)', '\1,' ) as text
FROM DUAL
CONNECT BY LEVEL <= LENGTH(regexp_replace('STRINGABCXYZ', '(.)', '\1,' )) 
    - LENGTH(REPLACE(regexp_replace('STRINGABCXYZ', '(.)', '\1,' ),',')))
) innerquery
```